# SoapUI OAuth 2.0 setting scope

Tags: json, rest, oauth, scope, soapui

How can I set the scope property while accessing the token in SoapUI using OAuth 2.0 method?
[image: Setting scope in SoapUI]

I can get the token manually by creating the post request and specifying body of the request as following:

```
{
   "grant_type":"client_credentials",
   "scope":{
      "userId":"user",
      "companyId":"company",
      "userType":"userType",
      "resourceType":"resource_api"
} }
```

But I can't get the token automatically in get request by setting the authorization OAuth 2.0, because I get the error:

> Thu Mar 02 09:52:14 CET 2017:ERROR:An error occurred [OAuthProblemException{error='unsupported_response_type', description='Invalid response! Response body is not application/json encoded', uri='null', state='null', scope='null', redirectUri='null', responseStatus=0, parameters={}}], see error log for details
>
> Thu Mar 02 09:52:14 CET 2017:ERROR:An error occurred [org.apache.oltu.oauth2.common.exception.OAuthSystemException: OAuthProblemException{error='unsupported_response_type', description='Invalid response! Response body is not application/json encoded', uri='null', state='null', scope='null', redirectUri='null', responseStatus=0, parameters={}}], see error log for details

Comment: Try doing URL encoding to the scope before sending it. https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/Re-OAuth-2-Flow-Error-getting-token-due-to-bad-request/td-p/111784